# Turning list from str into float with more then 2 decimal places

Tags: python, string, floating-point, decimal, precision

I'm trying to turn a list with strings into a list with floats.
The strings are all numbers with more then 2 decimal places (most of them have 6 decimal places).

The problem is that Python is only keeping two of the decimal places of the string (it's actually rounding). But I need all of the decimal places.

My code is as following:

```
timestamps_list_3 = []
for i in range(len(timestamps_list_2)):
    timestamps_list_3.append(float(timestamps_list_2[i]))
```

The content of timestamps_list_2 looks like this:

```
['1525356511.394770', '1525356511.438828', '1525356511.477972', '1525356511.506286', '1525356511.533924']
```

timestamps_list_3:

```
[1525356511.40, 1525356511.44, 1525356511.48, 1525356511.51, 1525356511.53]
```

Comment: `1525356511.394770 == 1525356511.39477`. Everything is fine.

Comment: If you need the trailing zero, don't use floats. Keep strings.

Comment: Ouch! I'm so sorry for pasting the wrong content of timestamps_list_3. It actually  only has two decimal places! I changed it above.

Comment: Please show the code that you used to generate the final output. Presumably you're `print`ing the individual floats?

Comment: Can't reproduce here, either on Python 2 or Python 3. There's almost certainly something you're not showing us or not telling us here.

Comment: I finally fixed it by reading the list from a file as strings. Then I used map for changing the strings into floats. That was the only way to make it working for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use decimal class from python like -

```
import decimal
timestamps_list_3 = [decimal.Decimal(i) for i in timestamps_list_2]
```

but this will give you numbers with decimal class but it will retain the 0 if it's the last digit in a number.

Else use float and it will remove the 0 if it's the last digit in a number like -

```
timestamps_list_3 = [float(i) for i in timestamps_list_2]
```

Let me know if it helps.

P.S. - You can do basic mathematical operations on decimal class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

64-bit floats can handle precision for up to around 16 decimal places.* So, as demonstrated in your question, you should not face any issues if your strings include at most 6 digits after the period.

For greater accuracy (default 28 decimal places, but user-definable), you should use the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module, but first make sure this is necessary. Computations will become expensive relative to `float`.

```
from decimal import Decimal

L = ['1525356511.394770', '1525356511.438828',
     '1525356511.477972', '1525356511.506286',
     '1525356511.533924']

res = list(map(Decimal, L))

print(res)

[Decimal('1525356511.394770'), Decimal('1525356511.438828'),
 Decimal('1525356511.477972'), Decimal('1525356511.506286'),
 Decimal('1525356511.533924')]
```

* See [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format: binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64):

> The 53-bit significand precision gives from 15 to 17 significant
>   decimal digits precision (2<sup>−53</sup> ≈ 1.11 × 10<sup>−16</sup>).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works fine now! I don't know why Python is only returning two decimal places with normal float...